How to update flutter mobile application Icon dynamically?
I am unable to find the solution for dynamic updation of flutter app icon.
we need to update app Icon dynamically, without release the app on either app store or play store, for flutter mobile application
we have a live app on play store and app store

Dynamically changing an app icon for a mobile application that has already been released on the App Store or Google Play Store is generally not feasible due to platform constraints. For iOS - Dynamic icon changes are not supported.
For android - Create multiple launcher activities with different icons and switch between them using PackageManager.

By "Mobile application Icon" Did you mean Launcher Icon or Material Icons?

It's not supported directly by Flutter, but you can use this package
flutter_dynamic_icon: 2.1.0

If you want to build in Android, the flutter_dyanmic_icon:2.1.0 package may not supported, you can use the package dynamic_icon_flutter:0.0.7 instead.
